# Read multiple files C++ using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to read the content of multiple files with the Boost library.
I have succeeded to list all the files in a folder but I am stuck at trying to read them...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // list all files in current directory.
    // You could put any file path in here, e.g. "/home/me/mwah" to list that
    // directory
    path p("/home/baptiste/Bureau");

    directory_iterator end_itr;

    // cycle through the directory
    for (directory_iterator itr(p); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
    {
        // If it's not a directory, list it. If you want to list directories too,
        // just remove this check.
        if (is_regular_file(itr->path())) 
        {
            // assign current file name to current_file and echo it out to the
            // console.
            string current_file = itr->path().string();
            cout << current_file << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Search for `fstream` and it's derivations (file streams)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ifstream` to open the file, and `getline()` to read its contents into a `string` line by line:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::string line;
std::ifstream ifs(itr->path().string().c_str());
if (ifs) {
    while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
        // Process line
    }
}
else {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't open " << itr->path().string() << " for reading\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the C++ standard library to read the file.

The most simple way to read a file line-by-line would be something like

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// ... and put this inside your loop:

if (std::ifstream inFile(current_file.c_str())) {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
         // Process line
    }
}
```

Comment: @BaptBnnt Do you want to open and read multiple files simultaneously instead of sequentially? Or even in parallel?

Comment: @BaptBnnt, this is an example. You would put code like this inside your loop over `directory_iterator` to read each file in turn.

Comment: the things is that i have multiple files in my folder the first function list all the file in the directory , but i also want to print their contents ...

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst thanks i will try i get back to you

Comment: go an error can't solve it... `"Description Resource Path Location Type
no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const string&)’ booost.cpp /booost/src line 35 C/C++ Problem
"`

Answer (score 0):

For those who want the entire code .

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

path p ("/home/baptiste/workspace/booost");

directory_iterator end_itr;


for (directory_iterator itr(p); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
{

    if (is_regular_file(itr->path())) {

        string current_file = itr->path().string();
        cout << current_file << endl; }

                            std::string line;
                            std::ifstream ifs(itr->path().string().c_str());
                            if (ifs) {
                            while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
                        cout<< line;
                    }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open " << itr->path().string() << " for reading\n";
    }

}
```

}